# UISegmentedControl - Missing return in a closure expecting return 'UISegmentedControl'

Tags: swift, xcode, return-value, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to hide nameTextField when toggled on Login and make it show toggled on Register. I've been trying to figure it out myself, but here is what I've got. I have gotten it down to two errors and they're the same. 
[Issue Navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAwiE.png)

```
lazy var loginRegisterSegmentControl: UISegmentedControl = {
    let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Login", "Register"])
    sc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sc.tintColor = UIColor.white
    sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 1

    switch sc.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
    case 0: self.nameTextField.isHidden = true
    case 1: self.nameTextField.isHidden = false
    default:
        break; 

    sc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLoginRegisterChange), for: .valueChanged)
    return sc

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.nameTextField.hidden = true
```

Comment: Thanks, now it says Missing Return in Closure

Answer (score 0):

```
lazy var loginRegisterSegmentControl: UISegmentedControl = {
    let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Login", "Register"])
    sc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sc.tintColor = UIColor.white
    sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 1

    switch sc.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
    case 0: self.nameTextField.isHidden = true
    case 1: self.nameTextField.isHidden = false
    default:
        break; 

    sc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLoginRegisterChange), for: .valueChanged)
    return sc

    }
}()
```